# How do I parameterize variables in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

For extensibility purposes I want to parameterize certain numbers and text in my iOS app. Is there a way to do this with a Config file or similar implementation?

For example, I'm using multiplier connectivity and there are a few places in my app where the same number needs to be used, such as the maximum number of peers allowed in the connection. Is there a way to turn this in to a parameter so that I can just change it in one file?

Comment: Please update your question showing some clear and specific examples of what you are referring to.

Comment: @rmaddy Updated

Comment: You could use static properties of a class or struct

Comment: @Paulw11 That's what I'm doing now, I was wondering if there's an 'official' method for this built into swift but if not I'll stick with that approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an official way to do this, however a common implementation in some projects is to create a `Constants.swift` file, where you store constant variables:

```swift
class Constants {

    static let maximumClients = 4

}
```

Which you can then use as `Constants.maximumClients` wherever desired. You could even go a step further and create different files for each "category" of constants to keep things organized:

```swift
class MultipeerConstants {

    static let maximumClients = 4

}

class UIConstants {

    static let leadingAndTrailingInsets: CGFloat = CGFloat(15)

}
```